# Add column and button magento 2

Tags: orders, adminhtml, sales-order

Is there any way to add a button and column at the backend order view items renderer?
I have tried multiples solution but did not work.

> sales_order_view

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_items">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="inventory_source" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Source</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
        <referenceBlock name="default_order_items_renderer">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="inventory_source" xsi:type="string" translate="true">col-source</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>

        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn" name="inventory_source"
               template="Test_DropShipping::order/items/source.phtml" group="column"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

> phtml file:

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Link to Product')) ?>
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
<div class="product-source">
    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Link to Product')) ?>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.Create file in app/code/[Vendor]/[Modulename]/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name=""order_items"">
            <arguments>
                <argument name=""columns"" xsi:type=""array"">
                    <item name=""custom_item_column"" xsi:type=""string"" translate=""true"">Custom Item Column</item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
            <referenceBlock name=""default_order_items_renderer"">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name=""columns"" xsi:type=""array"">
                        <item name=""custom_item_column"" xsi:type=""string"" translate=""true"">col-custom_item_column</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>

            <block class=""Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\DefaultColumn""
                   name=""column_custom_item_column""
                   template=""Smartosc_Sales::custom_item_column.phtml"" group=""column"" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2.Create file [Namespace]/[Modulename]/view/adminhtml/templates/custom_item_column.phtml folder and add the below code.

```
<?= __($block->getItem()->getData('custom_item_column')) ?>
```